# How to get KClass<List<String>> type from List<String> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect, kotlinpoet

I'm having problem with Kotlin poet `PropertySpec` object. Because i can't provide `List<String>` to the `PropertySpec` builder.

Help please.

```
PropertySpec.builder("services", List<String>::class.asTypeName()).build()
```

Comment: Hello Jamshed, welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. While you're at it, make sure you're familiar [with Type Erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: I'm not near my computer right now, so I can't provide a working example, but `KClass` can't store information about generics. You need `KType` which you can create using `typeOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

To add generics types info you need to use `parameterizedBy` for example

```
val stringList = ClassName("kotlin.collections", "List").parameterizedBy(String::class.asTypeName())
```